# How to reinstall all .deb packages?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, backup, packages

I have installed a number of packages with much pain. (I've a slow internet connection)

Now I want to reinstall Ubuntu (I use 10.10), but I don't want to download all the packages again.
I have burned a disk containing all these packages (with APTonCD, which I think don't solve dependency headache.)

Is there any easy way to override manual dependency solving? (Even though there is, I would like to know how to do it manually.)

Can I back up system configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question as best as I could, but I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for in your 3rd paragraph.  `apt` normally handles dependency resolution, but there should be options for allow installation of packages in a broken state.  Or else you could use `dpkg` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface with this:

- my Linux skills are rusty maybe out of date.
- I used to maintain 4 Ubuntu machines at home with a local package mirror.
- I have not tested these possibilities.

Ubuntu, does have [a package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage) to keeping a CD up-to-date.
Ubuntu and Debian can build install discs from a package mirror using [JigDo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JigdoDownloadHowto)

I would suggest Jigdo as your first option. I take it that bandwidth is at a premium by you.
Jigdo will build an updated install ISO given one or more package sources. One of these sources can be an existing install CD/DVD.  I believe that CD should be an existing install CD/DVD, but it wouldn't hurt to try pointing it to your APTonCD ISO you made.